# why redux store becomes empty in next js when I navigate from one page to another page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

In my first page I called API through getServerSideProps function, then i got 2 id's as a response, for example id-A and ID-B,
Now in my second page I want to call another API through getServerSideProps function, where I have to pass id-A and ID-B as a parameters to API.  how to get it?

What I have done is I stored api response in redux state, and I am trying to access redux state in second page to call api but it becomes null

Comment: `getServerSideProps` does not have access to the redux store from the client. Try passing the values you need through query params which you can retrieve inside `getServerSideProps`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have your redux provider at the app/top level (`_app.js`) instead of the `pages` level. Something like this in your `_app.js`

```js
export default function MyApp({ Component }) {

  return (
    <Provider store={yourStore}>
      <Component />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

If you instead have your `Provider` set up per page, then it means the store is recreated for every new page you visit.